# Extract table procedure Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, erp

Is it possible to create any procedure to extract tables from Oracle database?
Something like i could select which table and which fields that i want to extract, so finally create a CSV file of table. In future i will need for oracle ERP too, but at this time just for database.
I'm working in a audit project, so field consultants needs constantly extract tables from clients, and all this is by hand-made (table per table, script per script, there is so many waste time). So this way i'm trying to automated these extractions.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are many, many ways to do this.  Question is too broad.  You can simply use sqlplus and spool output to a file, or create a procedure that uses UTL_FILE package to write to a file on the server.  If you have a **specific** issue, please please a question about htat.

Comment: This problem is a little tougher than it might look at first.  There are some issues with commas in values, date formats, performance, etc.  I'd recommend starting with a pre-existing procedure, such as https://github.com/jonheller1/data_dump/blob/master/data_dump.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just give you the idea.

Create a `procedure` which accepts the `Table name` and `comma-separated column names` as two input parameters with a third `out` parameter which will be used to pass the status of the procedure at the end to the calling user.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FETCH_TABLE_DATA( P_IN_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                   P_IN_CS_COLUMN_NAMES IN VARCHAR2,
                                   P_OUT_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2)
```

You can now create the cursor using dynamic query and use something like:

```
'SELECT ' || COLUMN_NAMES_COMMA_SEPRATED || ' FROM ' || TABLE_NAME
```

and using `UTL_FILE`, you can put this all data to the text file.

In case of success, you can assign the name of the file to the `P_OUT_MESSAGE` or in case of failure, You can show the error message by assigning error message to `P_OUT_MESSAGE`

Search all the keywords used in the answer to prepare the procedure by yourself.

Hope, It will give you proper direction.

Cheers!!

Comment: In this method, can i choose any table from DB? Or i need to specify wich table in code that i want?

Comment: You need to pass table name from db and its column to this proc

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much, i will try this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Developer or Toad for Oracle, you can simply export a query on a table or the whole table to csv.

Oracle SQL Developer:
This is by far the easiest way for someone not familiar with complex PL/SQL stored procedures to export data.

One way to do this is to create a Report in SQL Developer (see this tutorial at Oracle for more information on this feature) and export the results

Once the report is created and ran, right click on the results grid and choose “Export” from the context menu
In the next screen select CSV as the format and enter in the filename.csv and location
You can also export a single table by:

Right-click the table name in the object tree view.
Select Export.
Select CSV. The Export Data window shows up.
Click Format tab.
Select Format as: CSV
Enter a file name and location.
Click Columns tab.
Check the columns you wish to export
Click Where tab and add any criteria needed to filter the data
Click Apply.

PL/SQL:
The best way to export data via PL/SQL is to create a stored procedure that uses the UTL_FILE command.

For a great example stored procedure for this, please see this article at oracle.com.  Note that there is a recommended change to the original stored procedure located in the comments (properly handles the quoting of data with reserved CSV characters).

Now you are ready to upload the new CSV File to SpatialKey.